# Assign values in pandas based on condition on array of values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes and same number of arrays which represents intervals(break numbers) in `price` column in these dataframes

I need to assign new column called `description_contrib` based on these intervals, e.g. if price is 16 USD and interval array looks like this `[0,10]` that means `description_contrib` column for this row will be 2, because 16 is greater then 0 and also greater than 10

I come up with this code:

```
def description_contribution(df_cat):
    for i in range(0, len(df_cat)):
        for j in range(0, len(intervals[i])):
            df_cat[i]['description_contrib'].loc[df_cat[i]['price'] >= intervals[i][j]] = j
```

But it runs slow and there is probably more robust solution for this

How can i improve this?

**UPD** Data looks like this

```
train_id    item_condition_id   brand_name  price   shipping    description_contrib
5644        1                   Unknown     15.0    1           6
12506       1                   Unknown     8.0     1           3
26141       1                   Unknown     20.0    1           8
```

And intervals for this dataframe is:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 20.0, 22.0, 31.0]
```

Comment: Can we see some data please?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Added

Comment: Does this give you what you're looking for? `(df.price.values[:, None] > intervals).sum(1)` It should be pretty damn fast.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it is fast) thanks

Comment: Faster than the current answer? If you would like, I can write an answer you can accept. Otherwise, it's alright.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ slightly faster. You can submit full answer, i will accept it

Comment: Cheers, done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a broadcasted comparison with the numpy arrays -

```
v = (df.price.values[:, None] > intervals).sum(1)
```

This can be assigned back to `df` -

```
df['description_contrib'] = v
```

The caveat with this is the memory usage, especially for larger data. A fair tradeoff for the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, the first option to speed things up is to replace loops with a vectorized operation. For example, you can make your code faster and more readable this way:

```
import pandas as pd

intervals = [0, 10]
df_cat = pd.DataFrame({'price': range(100)})
df_cat['description_contrib'] = sum(df_cat['price'] > v for v in intervals)
```

Assuming that df_cat has many rows and there are few intervals, this will give you a good performance. Still, faster ways may exists.